# Stop lapply from printing to console

Tags: r

When I use `lapply` and print to the console it prints unwanted `[[i]]NULL` though I want the intended message to print to the console.  I've tried `suppressWarnings` and `suppressMessages` but these do not remove the unwanted offender.  I searched `lapply` and don't see an argument to silence it.  This is more aesthetic as it doesn't interfere with the function.  I'm not opposed to allternative printing to the console so long as the user can turn it off if they wish.

Here's an example function, the output and what I'd like to get:

**Sample function:**

```
FUN <- function(x) {
    FUN2 <- function(z) message(z)
    lapply(1:3, function(i) FUN2(paste(x, i)))
}

FUN("hello")
```

**Output:**

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

**Desired Output:**

```
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
```

Comment: use `purrr::walk` instead of `lapply`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use `invisible`, eg:

```
invisible(FUN("hello"))
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
```

You can wrap it around the `lapply` call in the function too to make it tidier.

Comment: Perfect.  I'll add mark it as correct as soon as the time expires.  Works great (I wrapped the call to `lapply` as you suggested),

Comment: Still not sure why this works.  I've used invisible many times but not for this purpose.

Comment: It temporarily disables printing of the returned object.

Comment: It's not `lapply` printing its progress as you seem to think, its R printing the returned object as James says. That's why there's no option to `lapply` that you could see. Doing `junk <- FUN("hello")` would have the same visual effect.

Answer (score 9):

Use `l_ply` from plyr:

```
library(plyr)
FUN <- function(x) {
    FUN2 <- function(z) message(z)
    l_ply(1:3, function(i) FUN2(paste(x, i)))
}
FUN("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plain ol' for loop instead of `lapply()`:

```r
FUN <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:3) {
    message(paste0(x, i))
  }
}
FUN("hello")
```