# How to stop lapply from printing into the console?

Tags: r, console, apply

I'm reading a bunch of shapefiles into R and using `lapply` to run it across a bunch of files. Right now, the code works fine, but it prints a lot of info into the console. I'm trying to get rid of that so that the console is cleaner.

```
load_shapefiles <- function(file_name){
#grabs the last two digits of the year for the current file
partial_year <- str_sub(file_name, start = 9, end = 10)
#read in files
st_read(dsn = sprintf("data/%s", file_name), layer = sprintf("Census_sum_%s", partial_year))
}

#apply the loading function across a list of file names
list_data <- lapply(list_filenames, function(x) load_shapefiles(x))
```

The code runs really quickly, but for every file prints out some information like this:

`Reading layer 'Census_sum_17' from data source xxxx using driver ESRI Shapefile
Simple feature collection with xxxxx features and xxxxxx fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: xxxx ymin: xxxxxx xmax: xxxxxx ymax: xxxxxxx
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string: xxxxx`

Note: I substituted 'xxxx' for actual values.

I'd like to keep it from printing this info into the console. I've tried wrapping `lapply` and the function within `lapply` in `invisible()` [as recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984991/stop-lapply-from-printing-to-console). Neither approach worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `invisible(load_shapefiles(x))`, since it's this function that is printing those messages. Or `capture.output` instead of `invisible`.

Comment: `capture.output` worked. For some reason, `invisible` didn't do it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `capture.output(load_shapefiles(x))` worked where `invisible(load_shapefiles(x))` did not.

Thanks to Rui Barradas for the answer

EDIT: `st_read` has a parameter called `quiet` which determines whether or not it will print info about the file that it is reading. Setting `quiet` to TRUE eliminates the need to wrap the function in `capture.output` or `invisible`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Upvote, it might be of use to others, the main purpose of SO.